# How do you use keyboard-driven programs with non-latin alphabet keyboards?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, language

#### tl;dr

If I use keyboard-driven programs in my system, where letters like <kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>l</kbd>, <kbd>i</kbd>, <kbd>d</kbd>, <kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>o</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd> multiple times a second, how can I write text in non-latin alphabet across all applications?

#### Longer version

The reason for this question is simply that I'm learning russian in my spare time and wanted to start using a computer rather than a phone for the purpose of making exercise.

So I set up a keyboard shortcut to switch between my ordinary layout (italian querty) to a phonetic russian layout. Good.

But then the obvious question started as soon as I was not able to enter insert mode in by bash session: how in the world am I gonna use my system at all, considering that I have **every single program** keyboard-driven?

Here's a list of just a few:

- text editor: Vim
- web browser: qutebrowser
- file explorer: ranger
- window manager: i3
- shell: bash with **`vi-editing-mode`**
- ...

In each of those, having access to latin letters like <kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>l</kbd>, <kbd>i</kbd>, <kbd>d</kbd>, <kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>o</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd>, is vital. Fundamental.

But if I'm using a non-latin layout... I'm lost! Initially, when experimenting, I had a hard time even just changing back to italian layout. In order to run `sudo` I even had to compose my own password harvesting letters and symbols from the terminal output via mouse (select-the-letter-and-then-hit-the-wheel-to-paste-it)!

I mean, I want to type cyrillic letters only when I'm inserting text, not when I'm not.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the obvious solution - add a layout switcher.

For example, a standard switch (which was introduced in Windows and migrated to many Linux systems) - `Left Alt + Left Shift`. So you would type commands on Latin layout, hit `i` to switch into insert mode of `vi`. Hit `lAlt+lShift` type anything you like on a second layout. Switch again and use letter-commands of `vi` again.

Yes, it would be kind of pain, but I never heard about using non-latin keyboards with `vi`. Multilingual texts are for GUI editors (LibreOffice Write for example is perfect for school exercises), not for console editors.

The `xkb` also has ability to do a temporary switch, while a special key is pressed (Left Alt, or Left Win, or Right Alt, etc) So 'LeftAlt+a' become 'ф'.

And yes, in the time before X11, we did write multilingual texts, but in a normal text editors, like a builtin into `Midnight Commander`, or `emacs`, even `nano` is better suited for that.

Comment: Probably the least worst switcher I can use is CapsLock. I don't use it often by itself, and it's only one key, rather than a combination.