# Is there an API to query setxkbmap's current layout?

Tags: keyboard-layout, api, setxkbmap

A bit related to [this previous question of mine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/723777/how-do-you-use-keyboard-driven-programs-with-non-latin-alphabet-keyboards), I wonder if there's a way to query what is the current layout.

Say I have run

```bash
setxkbmap -layout it,ru -variant ,phonetic -option 'grp:caps_toggle'
```

and that I've presset <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> a few times. How can I tell programmatically what of 2 states I'm in?

Interactively I can simply type some characters to check, but I want to do it programmatically, so I can have that state printed in a status bar or something.

---

I was also thinking of some hack, like synthetically hitting <kbd>CapsLock</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>CapsLock</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>, and then checking whether the output is `фf` or `fф`, which would tell me the current layout is `it` or `ru` respectively.

[`xdotool` seemed the correct tool for this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/267704/command-to-simulate-keyboard-input), but unfortunately `Caps_Lock` corresponds to the *function* of the ordinary <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key, and not to what the `setxkbmap` command above has set it to, so this

```bash
xdotool key Caps_Lock f Caps_Lock f
```

results in `Ff` regardless of what layout is active.

Comment: Does this help? [check-lock-keys-state-from-command-line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541784/check-lock-keys-state-from-command-line)

Comment: @aviro, no, it doesn't. Like `xdotool` seems to not know about the behavioral change that `setxkbmap` has applied to CapsLock.